# Is there any Installer include ODBC feature?

Tags: java, installation

I want to create an installer for my java desktop application, instead of Advanced Installer is there any other installer include ODBC configuration?

Comment: What do you want to do with ODBC? You shouldn't use the JDBC-ODBC bridge driver for "real" applications; instead, use the appropriate JDBC driver for the brand and version of the database that you're using to access the database directly, without ODBC in between.

Comment: My database is Microsoft Access 2007 I want to distribute my java applciation to my friends, I tried using Advanced Installer, is there any other installer can include database?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

InstallShield has an "ODBC Resources" view.  Here's a summary:

> One of the more complex areas of
>   system configuration involves setting
>   up ODBC drivers, data source names
>   (DSNs), and translators. The ODBC
>   resource must be properly registered
>   on the system with all of the required
>   attributes and, in the case of drivers
>   and translators, install the necessary
>   files, including any installation .dll
>   files. This process is simplified in
>   the ODBC Resources view, in which you
>   can select the drivers, data sources,
>   and translators installed on your
>   development system.

[InstallShield help on ODBC](http://kb.flexerasoftware.com/doc/Helpnet/installshield16helplib_sp1/IHelpISXODBCOverview.htm)